# Comparing String in Rescript

Tags: reason, rescript

After browsing through [Rescript's API](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/api/js/string-2#link), it seems like there is no function that compares 2 strings that returns a boolean. The best option is `localeCompare` but it behaves somewhat different from the JS's `==`. Why does `localeCompare` return a float instead of an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare strings using `==` in rescript as well. Alternatively there is a `String.equal` as well if you need a function restricted to strings specifically, The "native" (non-`Js`) standard library modules such as `String` unfortunately seems to be left out of the rescript documentation entirely.

`localeComapre` probably returns a `float` because it might be possible for it to return non-integer numbers. JavaScript unfortunately has no integer type, which makes it hard to know if it *could* return `float`s even if it seems obvious that it shouldn't. I've seen several of this kind of bugs myself in various bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After browsing carefully, I do not see String.equal in Rescript's JS API, do you mind double checking this?

Comment: It isn't in the `Js` API. It's part of OCaml's standard library, which rescript builds on, and is documented [here](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stdlib.String.html). note that rescript is based on the 4.06 release of OCaml (last time I checked). Anything added after that won't be available.